# Conditional formatting of plot using ggplot2

Tags: r, function, ggplot2, conditional-statements

I am writing a custom package that leverages ggplot2. The purpose is to make standard plots that follow company branding and style.

Within the functions a user would identify inputs to arguments. Depending on the plot type the scale used would need to be different (i.e. discrete values vs. continuous values). I would like the function to select the appropriate scale based on the data type of the argument.

```
scatter_plot_multiple <- function(data, xaxis, yaxis, grouping, title = "", subtitle = "", xlabel = "", ylabel = "") {
      xaxis <- enquo(xaxis)
      yaxis <- enquo(yaxis)
      grouping <- enquo(grouping)
      
      ggplot(data) +
        aes(!!xaxis, !!yaxis, colour = !!grouping) +
        geom_point() +
        labs(title = title,
             subtitle = subtitle,
             x = xlabel,
             y = ylabel) +
        customTheme() +
        custom_scale_colour()
}
```

Within the previous function I would like the `custom_scale_colour()` to change based on the data type of the `grouping` argument. For example:

`scatter_plot_multiple(mpg, cty, hwy, drv)` would use custom_scale_colour()

`scatter_plot_multiple(mpg, cty, hwy, cyl)` would use custom_gradient_colour()

I am unsure how to tackle this challenge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In ggplot2, you can add a conditional statement like you can in a magrittr/dplyr pipe. One inserts an if statement wrapped in curly brackets: `+ {if ([condition]) {[action]}}`. Applied to quoted variable names inside a function, using this approach could look like the following.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(rlang)

scatter_plot_multiple <- function(data, xaxis, yaxis, grouping, title = "", subtitle = "", xlabel = "", ylabel = "") {

  xaxis <- enquo(xaxis)
  yaxis <- enquo(yaxis)
  grouping <- enquo(grouping)
  groupingClass <- class(pull(data, as_name(grouping)))

  ggplot(data) +
    aes(!!xaxis, !!yaxis, colour = !!grouping) +
    geom_point() +
    labs(title = title,
         subtitle = subtitle,
         x = xlabel,
         y = ylabel) +
    customTheme() +
     {if (groupingClass == 'character') {
       custom_scale_colour()}} +
     {if (groupingClass == 'numeric') {
       custom_gradient_colour()}}
}
```

Comment: Thanks @rjen. Not sure I am understanding your solution correctly. It appears it is based on a specific value. What I am hoping to achieve is conditional based on the data type. So if the column identified is numeric then the function would “choose” the custom_gradient_colour, where if the column is a string then the function would “choose” the custom_scale_colour. My assumption is the column needs to be assess for its “type” and based on that a conditional statement is executed, plus other things as well.

Comment: @Ryan Garnett: I have edited my answer. I deleted the example and typed out the solution.

Comment: Thanks @rjen this is great

Comment: I tested it and got the following error: Error in scatter_plot_multiple(mpg, cty, hwy, drv) : object 'drv' not found

Any ideas as to why the function cannot see the column?

Comment: @Ryan Garnett: I have edited my solution. It now also shows how  the approach can work with quoted variable names inside a function.